# Granular policy document permissions in AWS

Tags: permissions, amazon-s3, authorization, amazon-web-services, group-policy

I want to be able to allow users created through IAM to be able to view one specific bucket **in the management console**. Furthermore, I want to restrict it to a folder within the bucket, such that the permissions would be:

S3 Console access for my-bucket/folder/*

How would I do this using the policy generator? I currently have:

```
{
   "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I modify the Resource location -- `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/folder` -- it prevents the user from being able to use the console at all. Is this possible to do and what do I need to do to be able to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The policy for this reminded me of doing an Euler apporximation, but this is how I did it (with comments to explain):

```
{
  "Statement": [
{             // first, allow unlimited access for S3
  "Effect": "Allow",  
  "Action": "s3:*",
  "Resource": "*"
},
{             // second, deny access to all buckets except for the particular bucket
  "Action": [
    "s3:*"
  ],
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Resource": [
    list-of-my-other-buckets
  ]
},
{             // third, since we've already given * permissions, the bucket has full 
              // permissions, and we need to restrcit all the permissions we don't want to give
  "Action": [
    "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
    "s3:CreateBucket",
    "s3:DeleteBucket",
    "s3:DeleteObject",
    "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
    "s3:GetBucketAcl",
    "s3:GetBucketNotification",
    "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
    "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
    "s3:GetObjectAcl",
    "s3:GetObjectVersion",
    "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
    "s3:PutBucketAcl",
    "s3:PutBucketNotification",
    "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
    "s3:PutBucketRequestPayment",
    "s3:PutBucketVersioning",
    "s3:PutObjectAcl",
    "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl"
  ],      
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
          ]
        }
    ]
}
```